# Docker cannot apply checked shared drives

Tags: docker, driver, shared

**Expected behavior**

- I went to Settings->Shared Drives and set checkbox on my F: drive.
- After i pressed apply and input my user and password, i want to see then checkbox with drive F: is checked.

**Docker Version**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTQTF.png)

**Actual behavior**

- I checked the checkbox of F:, and press apply

[image]

- input my user and password

[image]

- the checkbox of F: retrieve unchecked

[image]

**Inspection of my bound container**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6caB.png)

**Docker container logs**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCgFA.png)

**Ways I tried but did not work**

- close firewall software
- change permission mode of local file to 777
- start UPnP Device Host and SSDP Discovery

**Related issues:**

https://forums.docker.com/t/volume-mounts-in-windows-does-not-work/10693/9
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/579

Comment: Please, edit the question so that the images are embedded into the question.

Comment: sorry, I'm new here so still not have enough reputations to display img

Comment: Ok, my bad. I enabled some images. The rest of images are screenshots of text, please, add these as text, and format it (using the `{}` button).

Answer (score 2):

in my case (win.10), worked with my Microsoft password..

> > In the password part, try your PC formal PW. Example:

PC:  User: samle_id@outlook.com
     PW:   ********(official email pw)

Comment: Most underrated comment in stackoverflow. This should be as the accepted solution. Along with @dbokers answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a Win 10. I solved this issue by switching off the Experimental features.

Go to Settings -> Daemon -> Uncheck Experimental features. It should restart automatically and you should be able to check the F: Drive then